# Is it possible to save several values to a button?

Tags: javascript, html, button, dom-events

Traditionally buttons are designed to save only **ONE** single value, eg:

```
<button type="button" value="Love" onclick="fetchValue(this)"> Primary </button>

function fetchValue(_button){  
  alert(_button.value);
}
```

For instance, in the above `HTML` code, when a user clicks on the **Primary** button, an alert with the word **Love** will pop up!

For (UI/UX)User Interface/Experience purposes, I need to design a button that can hold several values and **NOT** just one value. This is because I plan on coupling a **click event** to the button to send/post **all** stored values.

The much desired code would be something like the code below:

```
<button type="button" value="Love", value2="Love", 
value3="Love" onclick="fetchValue(this)"> Primary </button>
```

Is there someone who might know how to resolve this or even a better solution to my problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can for example encode an array as JSON, and then put that into the value. Your JavaScript then reads this string, and decodes it again.

Comment: You can use `data-XXX` attributes to hold additional values.

Comment: @Barmar Do you mind demonstrating in code?

Comment: @CBroe Do you mind demonstrating in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use the dataset to set multiple values to the button instead of using the traditional value attribute. if you use `data-attribute_name` then you can access all your dataset values as a single JS Object then you can choose and reformat all required values from there. For Example

```js
function fetchValue(_button){
  // To get all value data as JS Object use _button.dataset
  console.log("JS Object Data:\r\n")
  console.log(_button.dataset)
  
  // To get all value data as JSON use JSON.stringify(_button.dataset)
  console.log("\r\n\r\nJSON Data:\r\n")
  console.log(JSON.stringify(_button.dataset))
  
  // To access the specific value you can use _button.dataset.name_here from data-name_here
  console.log("\r\n\r\nSpecific Data:\r\n")
  console.log(_button.dataset.value1)  
  console.log(_button.dataset.value2)
}
```

```html
<button data-value1="Something 1" data-value2="Something 2" data-value3="Something 3" onclick="fetchValue(this)">
Click Me
</button>
```

If you want to get all value rendered togather you can simply use the `.map()` function inside the up `fetchValue()` function.

```js
let allValues = _button.dataset.map((value) => {
  return `${value} `;
});

console.log(`All values are: ${allValues}`);
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution is excellent, though I have a slight issue, how do I get the values of **value** and **data-value2** if they were captured from a **for loop**? 

For example, when my code looks like this:  `<'button type="button" value=' + item.tokenId + 'data-value2=' + item.message + 'onclick="fetchValue(this)" '> Primary <'/button'>`

I noticed that I am **NOT** able to properly capture the contents of `item.message` especially if it has many words.

Comment: If you want to loop you can use tge .map() function. And instead if using `value` and `data-value2` you have to use `data-value1` and `data-value2` you have to use all property using tge prefix `data-*` instead if direct `value`. So when you have updated your code to use the data-* prefix uding use the bellow map function

Comment: You can see my answer i've updated it with tge .map() function

Comment: @udoyhasab Thanks, I think I might not have been clear enough, kindly refer to my other post where I belive I am christal clear: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71392661/how-do-i-correctly-save-values-into-my-data-attributes

Comment: Ok. Check your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71392661/how-do-i-correctly-save-values-into-my-data-attributes/71394199#71394199

Comment: And I hope if my answer help you you will mark both answers as the answer so other people get benefited who are currently facing or in future will face this kind of problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can either store them as dataset values

```
<button value="love" data-value1="hate" data-value2="happy" onclick="fetchvalue(this)" >click me</button>
```

And access them in js like

```
function fetchvalue(_button){
alert(_button.value)
alert(_button.dataset.value1)
alert(_button.dataset.value2)
}
```

Or access them in a json like format

```
<button value={value1:"hate",value2:"happy" } onclick="fetchvalue(this)" >click me</button>
```

And access them in js like

```
function fetchvalue(_button){
alert(_button.value.value1)
alert(_button.value.value2)

}
```

Comment: Thanks your solution is helpful though I have a slight issue, how do I get the values of **value** and **data-value2** if they were captured from a **for loop**? 

For example, when my code looks like this:  `<'button type="button" value=' + item.tokenId + 'data-value2=' + item.message + 'onclick="fetchValue(this)" '> Primary <'/button'>`

I noticed that I am **NOT** able to properly capture the contents of `item.message` especially if it has many words.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `data` attributes for additional values.

```js
function fetchValue(_button){  
  alert(`${_button.value} ${_button.dataset.value2}`);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" value="Love" data-value2="you" onclick="fetchValue(this)"> Primary </button>
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution is excellent, though I have a slight issue, how do I get the values of **value** and **data-value2** if they were captured from a **for loop**? 

For example, when my code looks like this:  `<'button type="button" value=' + item.tokenId + 'data-value2=' + item.message + 'onclick="fetchValue(this)" '> Primary <'/button'>`

I noticed that I am **NOT** able to properly capture the contents of `item.message` especially if it has many words.

Comment: Make sure you put quotes around the attribute value if it can have spaces. `data-value2="' + item.message + '"`

Comment: I recommend you use a template literal instead of concatenation. It's more readable and you'll notice problems like this more easily.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a lookup table to not clutter the HTML

Here I delegate event listeners too

```js
const values = {
  "Love": ["Adore", "Be fond of"],
  "Hate": ["Dislike", "Despise"]
};
document.getElementById("buttons").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const button = e.target.closest("button");
  if (button.matches(".fetchbutton")) console.log(values[button.value]);
})
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
  <button type="button" value="Love" class="fetchbutton"> Love </button>
  <button type="button" value="Hate" class="fetchbutton"> Hate </button>
</div>
```