# How do I correctly save values into my data- attributes?

Tags: javascript, html, custom-data-attribute

I am failing to save some values (*that I get through a `for loop`*) into an `HTML button` as the buttons `data- attributes`.

In the following `for loop` code, you will notice how I indicate that the values are successfully captured by `console` login them out.
Why am I failing to save them in the buttons **data-attributes** can someone point out where I am going wrong?

Find below the code to my `for loop` and its successful `console log` results:

```
contractMethods.viewAllGifts().call( (error, result)=> {
  if(!error){
      result.forEach((item, index)=>{
        console.log("item.tokenId: " +item.tokenId);
        console.log("item.messageToRecipient: " +item.messageToRecipient);
        $('#assetInheritor').append('<button type="button" value=' + item.tokenId + ' ' + 'data-value1=' + item.messageToRecipient + ' ' + ' onclick="fetchValue(this)"> ' + item.tokenId + '</button>  ');
      })
   } 
})
```

The `console` in the code above, successfully logs out:

```
item.tokenId: 100
item.messageToRecipient: I love you Mamma!
```

Find below the code to the `onclick="fetchValue()` and its errornous results:

```
function fetchValue(_button){  
  console.log(_button.value);
  console.log(_button.dataset.value1)
  
}
```

The first `console` logs out: `100`, instead of: **100**

while the second one `console` logs out: `I` instead of:  **I love you Mamma!**

Can someone kindly point out where I am going wrong?

Thanks
the second

Comment: Typo: You forgot to put a space between the value and data-value1 attributes so the latter is treated as part of the former.

Comment: You should have logged the string you are appending (or not used string mashing to generate HTML in the first place).

Comment: I edited the code by putting space between the value and data-value1.

Am not sure I understand your solution of "not using the mashing to generate HTML in the first place" 

Do you can to care to demonstrate in code?

Comment: Use `attr()` to set attributes for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your problem is that you are appending a button each time for a single. Instead of setting a button like that use attr to set an attribute after the button was appended:

```js
// Dummy data
const result = [
  {
    tokenId: 100,
    messageToRecipient: "Message 1",
  },
  {
    tokenId: 101,
    messageToRecipient: "Message 2",
  }
]


// updated forEach
result.forEach((item, index)=>{
  $('#assetInheritor').append(`<button id="button-${index}" onclick="fetchValue(this)">Button ${index + 1}</button> <br/> <br/>`);
  $(`#button-${index}`).attr("data-value1", item.tokenId);
  $(`#button-${index}`).attr("data-value2", item.messageToRecipient);

})

// updated function
function fetchValue(_button){  
  console.log(_button.dataset.value1);
  console.log(_button.dataset.value2)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="assetInheritor"></div>
```